# Formatar data que vem do Banco de Dados SQL SERVER

Tags: javascript, html, sql-server

A data que vem do SQL SERVER vem no formato assim: 20181212.
Tentei formatar, mas só funciona se vier no formato 2018-12-12.

Eu coloco essa data dentro de uma tabela pela API que eu puxo onde ta os dados (data vem da API).

```
function Progress() {

        fetch('http://API_AQUI', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            body: `L2_PRODUTO=${id}`
        }).then(response => response.json().then(data => ({
            data: data,
            status: response.status
        })
        ).then(res => {
            res.data.map(element => {
                $('.progresso-1').append(`${element.DATAUM}`);
                 $('.progresso-2').append(`${element.DATADOIS}`);
            }
```

Aí no front eu coloco:

```
<tr>
    <td class="td-b">Data Um</td>
    <td class="progresso-1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="td-b">Data Dois</td>
    <td class="progresso-2"></td>
</tr>
```

Só que só vem no formato que da no bando de dados SQL SERVER: 20181212.

Eu tenho essa forma pronta:

```
                    function formatarData(str){
                    return [str.slice(0, 4), str.slice(4, 6), str.slice(-2)].join('/'); // para formato yyyy-mm-dd
                    // ou para retornar um objeto Date
                    return new Date(str.slice(0, 4), Number(str.slice(4, 6)) + 1, str.slice(-2));

                  }
                  function formatDate(str)
                  {
                      return str.split('/').reverse().join('/');
                  }
```

Mas fica vindo 2018/12/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode quebrar isso com o método `substr`, que pega parte de uma string usando de um parâmetro que diz de onde começar e outro parâmetro que diz quantos caracteres pegar a partir do inicial (se a quantia não for informada, vai pegar todos a partir do indice informado):

```
function formatDate( date ){
    if( typeof date === "number" ) date = date.toString();

    //Posição 0, 4 digitos = ano
    //Posição 4, 2 digitos = mes
    //Posição 6, 2 digitos = dia
    return `${date.substr( 6 )}-${date.substr( 4, 2 )}-${date.substr( 0, 4 )}`;
}
```

Ai vai ficar assim :

```
$( '.progresso-1' ).append( `${formatDate(element.DATAUM)}` );
$( '.progresso-2' ).append( `${formatDate(element.DATADOIS)}` );
```

Comment: fica 2018-01-23 e nao dd-mm-aaaa

Comment: É só trocar de lugar, foi só um exemplo, vou mudar pra você ver

Answer (score 0):

Eu ainda não consigo comentar.
A data que vai para ao banco de dados é inserido ou vem por defeito?
Já tentas-te usar php

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime( $row['date'] ))
```

Isto é um exemplo se fores buscar a data a um campo de base de dados

Mas podes sempre usar um código SQL para converção

```
CONVERT(data_type(length), expression, style)
```

Dá uma vista de olhos neste link

[CONVERT SQL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Por padrão, a data é guardada no banco de dados MsSql ou mySql no formato yyyy-mm-dd, como por exemplo hoje: 2019-11-07.

Então, uso apenas essa função bem simples:

```html
function dataBDFormatar(date){
 var strData = date.substr(8, 2)+"/"+date.substr(5, 2)+"/"+date.substr(0, 4);
    return strData;
}
```

O return será 06/11/2019